# Show different image in pictureBox when click button and before run function C#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I'm working on a Windows app in C#, when I click on button1 I run the function "MyFunction()". I'm trying to 
change the image in pictureBox1 while "MyFunction()" is running, since it takes some minutes to complete, but 
with the code I have so far the image desired is changed only after the execution of "MyFunction" has finished.

I see that the GUI freezes while MyFunction() is working, but I'm changing the image (pictureBox1.Image = Resource1.Working;) 
before to call "MyFunction();".

How can I show the image "working" in pictureBox1 inmediately before "MyFunction()" starts? Thanks

```
    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = Resource1.Working;//To show image "Working.jpg" while function is running

        MyFunction();

        pictureBox1.Image = Resource1.WorkCompleted;//To show image "WorkCompleted.jpg" when function finishes

        //End of program
    }
```

Comment: you can create a thread that changes the images of picture box.

Comment: There are couple existing questions on SO about dealing with "UI freezes when method takes long time" with many recommendations... Consider searching for existing questions...

Comment: Hi Jawad, thanks for your suggestion. I haven't work with threads before. If a thread to change the image is created, the current code I have remains the same or would change?

Comment: Hi Alexei, why the -1 to my question? my question is about how to change the image before running the function. I mentioned about the GUI freezes while function running as a information note.

Comment: "UI freezes" is the reason of behavior you observe (or to be precise - unable to observe as UI does not get updated). It is very common condition and discussed a lot on SO and everywhere else. Possible search terms - [c# update progress long running operation](http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20update%20progress%20long%20running%20operation&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=c%23%20update%20progress%20long%20running%20operation).

Comment: I understand Alexei what you mean, thank you for explain. I only don't understand why you voted "-1" to my question since before ask I didn't know the reason why pictureBox is not being updated, I know now after you explain me. If I had known before, maybe I would have looked about "UI freezes".

Answer (score 2):

a windows app is single threaded so your statements will execute sequentially on one thread, the main thread. Consider using async/await from .net 4.5 like this:

```
async void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Resource1.Working;

    await Task.Run(() => MyFunction());

    pictureBox1.Image = Resource1.WorkCompleted;
}
```

Comment: Hi Balanikas. Thank you for your help. I'm trying in SharpDevelop IDE and Run action for "Task" is not present (I know this is more about an ide issue). I've tried in Visual Studio and it seems to work. I'm not sure why is not working in SharpDevelop even when is working with NET 4.5. Maybe is needed an alternative way to use it in Sharp Develop. Thanks again